# Is there a way to set a fixed width for the characters in HTML?

Tags: python, pyqt4, qtextedit

Is there a way to set a fix size for the characters in HTML?
That means, say …

First row, 8th character is “Z”
Second row’s 8th character is “A”

I want to print out , when printed the “Z” has to be exactly on top of “A”

*Note: I'm using the insertHtml method in QTextEdit()

Comment: Did you forget to tag the question HTML?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're asking for is called a fixed-width font. As James Hopkin remarked, HTML text in `<tt>` or `<pre>` tags is rendered with a fixed-width font.

However, what you describe sounds like a table. HTML has direct support for that, with `<table>`, `<tr>` (row) and `<td>` (data/cell). Don't bother with fixed-width fonts; just put your A and the Z in the second `<td>` of their rows.

Comment: thx :)
although it looks a bit .... kinda wierd with the table td method, it does solve the issue :)
thx again.

Answer (score 0):

Put the text in `<tt>` tags (or `<pre>` around a whole paragraph of text).